# Why does overwriting __getattribute__ and __getattr__ cause __deepcopy__ to fail?

Tags: python, deep-copy

I want to do a hook in my custom class:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = {'key': 'value'}
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        if key not in self.data:
            raise AttributeError
        else:
            return self.data[key]
```

but after overwriting the `__getattr__` method, using `copy.deepcopy()` fails:

```
a = A()
deepcopy(a)

Fatal Python error: _Py_CheckRecursiveCall: Cannot recover from stack overflow.
Python runtime state: initialized
```

That means I get a `maximum recursion depth exceeded`. Why does overwriting `__getattribute__` and `__getattr__` causes deepcopy fail, and what should I do to fix it?

Comment: The error message is coming from completely different code from what you posted. The error message shows a `raise KeyError` line, which is not an error a `__getattr__` method should raise.

Comment: I get a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` error when I run your code with an empty `Data` class or a `Data` class with a `name` attr.

Comment: SO sorry about it. I edit the question and correct the error message. What I want to do is when I can not find an attribute from the instance then look up the member's attribute in this instance. I don't know how to rewrite __getattr__ and __getattribute__ and keep default behavior as same. Please help me ~ Thanks !